# Does it make sense to put a hyperlink into an answer within an interview?

Tags: style, formatting

Some media did an interview with me and published it - and I see a hyperlink inserted into my answer. I provided them the link separately but didn't expect to see it inside the quotation marks. 
What should I do? Is it really as much nonsense as it seems to me? 
Thanks for your reply.
(Sorry for my poor English...)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the link was to and how it relates to what you said. Oftentimes you will see people use [hyperlinking text](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~neha/hyperlinks/main-no.html) to provide further information on a topic without going off to explain something in greater detail. This is not uncommon as you can see this is also commonly practiced even in sites like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beringian_wolf) and my answer here with linking articles.

The important part is that the link goes with the flow of the topic and more of a stylistic choice. Why this writer chose to link words you said within the quote rather than after the quote is only known to him. I could not find anything on google that states anything for or against this practice.

I would say that if it bothers you that much, to reach out to the journalist who interviewed you to find out why they did it (especially if you do not want to be associated with the link). However, if you are curious if this is okay from a style point of view, there is nothing saying it can't be done that I have found.

Answer (score 0):

The only stylistic problem is that a *quote* is supposed to be an exact reproduction of something that has been said or written by someone. If you look at academic writing for example it would be unforgivable to add a hyperlink to a quote that wasn't there before without explicitly marking the hyperlink as an addition.

If you are bothered by this practice I would recommend the same thing [ggiaquin](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/31763/23159) mentioned: contact the journalist and politely ask him about the reasoning for doing this.

Most likely it was easier for potential readers to just incorporate the link into a place that fits instead of adding a few sentences that would explain why the hyperlink is related.

In general I would advise against this practice. Quotes are not supposed to be altered. Even if you mentioned something in the context of the quotation that could be linked, for example by adding a few sentences that were too long for the printed article or you referred to the linked source yourself, that should be marked visuably. For example a journalist could do something like the following:

> "And then I did this stuff. [The source our guest speaker mentioned.]"

And then format the sentence in brackets to be a link. This way it's obvious which part was what you said and which part was added by the journalist.

On the other hand if the journalist was only summarizing and paraphrasing what you said it would be perfectly normal to add links to the text, as was explained by ggiaquin in the answer *I linked above in the same way*.

As long as you don't feel the link did massively change the meaning of what you said, for example by providing a link to Wikipedia for a difficult technical term you used or something like that, I wouldn't be too concerned. But when dealing with this journalist again you might request that citations are not altered with links if it makes you uncomfortable. Just mention that this has happened before at an interview and that you thought it was a bit weird, they will understand and find other ways. Adding a link to the sentence before or after the quote is not a big problem.